# Hibernate IN clause wih postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am facing problem with IN clause in hibernate while using postgres.
I am using hibernate 3 and postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.

I am getting below exception

```
 ERROR :: [Ljava.lang.Long; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Long; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Please help me.

below is my code

```
final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TaskHistoryVO.class);
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
disjunction.add(Restrictions.in(TaskConstants.KEY_TASK_ID, taskIds));
detachedCriteria.add(disjunction);
if (customerId != null)
{
   detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq(TaskConstants.TABLE_CUSTOMER_ID, customerId));
}
List<TaskHistoryVO> taskHistoryVOList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
```

I am getting this error for parameter TaskConstants.KEY_TASK_ID in IN clause. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Long; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

This error indicates your are trying to cast an array of Long to Long ...

Comment: waiting for your reply.

Comment: It is not obvious to me where the error is being caused. But the exception is telling you what it is. Something is returning a Long[ ] and you are trying to assign it / cast to a Long